# Declaring lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Do I have to declare a list before using it in a loop?

for example:

```
For[i = 1, i < 10, i++, A[[i]] = i];
```

The output is:

```
Symbol A in part assignment does not have an immediate value
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: You need to initialize `A` first if you want your code to work as it is, e.g. like this: `A = ConstantArray[Null, 9]` or use. Better though to use `Table` or `Array`: `Array[# &, 9]`.

Comment: @jarhead, that is a useful [article](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite regular.

```
a = {};
For[i = 1, i < 10, i++, AppendTo[a, i]]
```

the result:

```
a
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

Otherwise you could do

```
a = ConstantArray[Null, 10 - 1];
For[i = 1, i < 10, i++, a[[i]] = i]
```

or

```
a = ConstantArray[Null, 10 - 1];
Array[(a[[#]] = #) &, 9]
```

Or simply using function variables:

```
Clear[a]

Array[(a[#] = #) &, 9]
```

but this does not give list `a`, although the elements can be referenced, e.g.

```
a[4]
```

> 4

Answer (score 5):

```
Table[i,{i, 10}]
```

OR

```
Range @ 10
```

OR

```
RandomInteger[100,10]
```

OR

```
RandomReal[1,10]
```

If you just want to generate a list you can use a set of functions such as:
[Table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html?q=Table), [Range](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html), [RandomInteger](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomInteger.html?q=RandomInteger), [RandomReal](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomReal.html?q=RandomReal) etc.

Also see associated tutorial for list generation: [Link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingListsOfObjects.html)

Comment: You missed the point, the calculation for A[[i]] is just an example....I have there a more complicated calculation

Comment: @jarhead I do apologise.

Comment: but thanks for the info though

Comment: @jarhead glad you found it useful!

Answer (score 5):

*Mathematica* is not a declarative language. Don't expect to declare things.

*Mathematica* is clumsy as a procedural language, so avoid `For[]` loops.

Avoid using upper case to start your symbol names to prevent conflicts with the thousands of built-in symbols.

Use a functional programming approach:

```
a = Table[i, {i, 1, 10}]
```